# Discord.js - How to search a song's lyrics by its title

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

Lets say you wanted to listen to any song with lyrics and maybe have a little fun, trying to sing it together with your friends, but you dont remember the words correctly!

Here does the Lyrics command for your Discord bot come in handy!

What we want to do is:

> Make a new command, we'll call it "lyricsearch.js" for now. This command will need to read the song title given by the user, and search it up with lyrics-finder, so lets see how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we declare the important stuff:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js"); //import discord.js
const lyricsFinder = require("lyrics-finder"); //import lyrics-finder

//start
module.exports = {
  name: "lyricsearch",
  aliases: ["lys", "searchlyrics"],

  async execute(message, args) {

//if the title isnt provided return
    if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Provide a title to search its lyrics");

//if url return
    if (args[0].startsWith("https://" || "http://")) return message.channel.send("Please use a song's title to search its lyrics");

//temporary "Loading status" embed
    let temEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor("Searching...", "optional.gif").setFooter("Lyrics")
      .setColor("#YOURCOLOR")
    let result = await message.channel.send(temEmbed)
```

Then we send the actual lyrics embed.

```
const search = args.join(" "); //specify that the valid arguments start after first space

let lyrics = null;

    try {
      lyrics = await lyricsFinder(search); //uses lyricsFinder to search for the title given on command
      if (!lyrics) lyrics = `No lyrics found for ${search}.`; //if none are found return 
    } catch (error) {
      lyrics = `No lyrics found for ${search}.`;
    }

    let lyricsEmbed = new MessageEmbed() //create an embed to either say "nothing found" or send the found lyrics
      .setTitle("Lyrics")
      .setDescription(lyrics)
      .setColor("#YOURCOLOR")
      .setTimestamp(); //optional

    if (lyricsEmbed.description.length >= 2048)
      lyricsEmbed.description = `${lyricsEmbed.description.substr(0, 2045)}...`; //to prevent characters limit errors, set the maximum words writable to 2045 and add "..." if the lyrics contain more
    return result.edit(lyricsEmbed).catch(console.error); //edit the temporary embed to final embed (you can also choose to send it as new message instead)
  }
};
```

After that, you're finished with your new command file, and you can try whatever song you can think of!

Comment: 4096 is the new limit of embeds description